# Rails, best practices for starting a scheduler like Rufus

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [Rufus](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) to schedule jobs to be run in the background, but the problem is, is that I'm not clear on when or how to start the scheduler in my app, like do I start it in the initializer? or do I make an action in a controller that starts the scheduler? Or do I put it in a model... I'm just not sure how to implement it.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to add it to initializers:

`config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.every("1m") do
  SomeClass.perform_tasks
end
```

Comment: This works! My issue is looking at the job queue afterwards, like I want to call `scheduler.jobs` later on from a particular controller, but it won't work because it's unaware of the scheduler. Is there som global way to see all jobs that Rufus is managing?

Comment: Maybe documentation can help you: http://rufus.rubyforge.org/rufus-scheduler/Rufus/Scheduler/JobQueue.html